# How to extract optimization problem matrices A,b,c using JuMP in Julia

Tags: matrix, optimization, julia, julia-jump

I create an optimization model in Julia-JuMP using the symbolic variables and constraints e.g. below

```
using JuMP
using CPLEX

# model
Mod = Model(CPLEX.Optimizer) 

# sets
I = 1:2;

# Variables
x = @variable( Mod , [I] , base_name = "x" ) 
y = @variable( Mod , [I] , base_name = "y" )  

# constraints
Con1 = @constraint( Mod , [i in I] , 2 * x[i] + 3 * y[i] <= 100 )

# objective
ObjFun = @objective( Mod , Max , sum( x[i] + 2 * y[i] for i in I) ) ;

# solve 
optimize!(Mod)
```

I guess JuMP creates the problem in the form minimize c'*x subj to Ax < b before it is passes to the solver CPLEX. I want to extract the matrices A,b,c. In the above example I would expect something like:

```
A
2×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  0  3  0
 0  2  0  3

b
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 100
 100

c
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
```

In MATLAB the function prob2struct can do this https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationproblem.prob2struct.html

In there a JuMP function that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not easily possible as far as I am aware.

The problem is stored in the underlying `MathOptInterface` (MOI) specific data structures. For example, constraints are always stored as `MOI.AbstractFunction` - in - `MOI.AbstractSet`. The same is true for the `MOI.ObjectiveFunction`. (see MOI documentation: https://jump.dev/MathOptInterface.jl/dev/apimanual/#Functions-1)

You can however, try to recompute the objective function terms and the constraints in matrix-vector-form.

For example, assuming you still have your `JuMP.Model` `Mod`, you can examine the **objective function** closer by typing:

```
using MathOptInterface
const MOI = MathOptInterface

# this only works if you have a linear objective function (the model has a ScalarAffineFunction as its objective)
obj = MOI.get(Mod, MOI.ObjectiveFunction{MOI.ScalarAffineFunction{Float64}}())

# take a look at the terms 
obj.terms
# from this you could extract your vector c
c = zeros(4)
for term in obj.terms
    c[term.variable_index.value] = term.coefficient
end
@show(c)
```

This gives indeed: `c = [1.;1.;2.;2.]`.

You can do something similar for the underlying MOI.**constraints**.

```
# list all the constraints present in the model
cons = MOI.get(Mod, MOI.ListOfConstraints())
@show(cons)
```

in this case we only have one type of constraint, i.e. `(MOI.ScalarAffineFunction{Float64}` in  `MOI.LessThan{Float64})`

```
# get the constraint indices for this combination of F(unction) in S(et)
F = cons[1][1]
S = cons[1][2]
ci = MOI.get(Mod, MOI.ListOfConstraintIndices{F,S}())
```

You get two constraint indices (stored in the array `ci`), because there are two constraints for this combination F - in - S.
Let's examine the first one of them closer:

```
ci1 = ci[1]
# to get the function and set corresponding to this constraint (index):
moi_backend = backend(Mod)
f = MOI.get(moi_backend, MOI.ConstraintFunction(), ci1)
```

`f` is again of type `MOI.ScalarAffineFunction` which corresponds to one row `a1` in your `A = [a1; ...; am]` matrix. The row is given by:

```
a1 = zeros(4)
for term in f.terms
    a1[term.variable_index.value] = term.coefficient
end
@show(a1) # gives [2.0 0 3.0 0] (the first row of your A matrix)
```

To get the corresponding first entry `b1` of your `b = [b1; ...; bm]` vector, you have to look at the constraint set of that same constraint index `ci1`:

```
s = MOI.get(moi_backend, MOI.ConstraintSet(), ci1)
@show(s) # MathOptInterface.LessThan{Float64}(100.0)
b1 = s.upper
```

I hope this gives you some intuition on how the data is stored in `MathOptInterface` format.

You would have to do this for all constraints and all constraint types and stack them as rows in your constraint matrix `A` and vector `b`.

Comment: You can also use `JuMP.objective_function(model)` and `JuMP.constraint_object(con)` instead of the `MOI.get` functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. Indeed, the solution is not straightforward, but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following lines:

```
Pkg.add("NLPModelsJuMP")

using NLPModelsJuMP

nlp = MathOptNLPModel(model) # the input "< model >" is the name of the model you created by JuMP before with variables and constraints (and optionally the objective function) attached to it.

x = zeros(nlp.meta.nvar)

b = NLPModelsJuMP.grad(nlp, x)

A = Matrix(NLPModelsJuMP.jac(nlp, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself. But the MathProgBase package seems to be able to provide A, b, and c in matrix form.